# Paragraph causing expand to look strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

So I'm making a simple gallery using scss and some simple Jquery. When clicking an image it expands within a div and shows some descriptive text underneath. This is done with a .3s animation.

Everything is technically working but as the div begins to expand, the paragraph causes the height to extend much quicker than the width, in order to contain the text in the paragraph.

I know why the issue is happening and I've tried fixes such as setting height: 0; width: 100%; then only expanding the height but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to stop this behaviour?

Images to show the issue:

https://ibb.co/h90ewK

https://ibb.co/dmtciz

https://ibb.co/jUjNGK

https://ibb.co/mBaUwK

A sample of the code:

The image:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <img src="https://intellidesign.000webhostapp.com/img/gallery-pg3-img1.jpg"         alt="Yellowstone National Park" 
        class="gallery__image"
        image-description="A gorgeous image of Yellowstone National Park at sunset"
        image-author="Unknown">
</div>
```

When clicking the image it's inserted into this div:

```
<div class="gallery__selected-image">
    <div class="gallery__selected-image-container" style="height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;">
        <img class="gallery__selected-image-full-width" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 2px 0 2px 0;">
        <div class="col col-1-of-3" style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
            <h1 class="gallery__selected-image-author"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-2-of-3" style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
            <p class="gallery__selected-image-description" style="width: 0;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The scss/css:

```
&__selected-image {
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
border-radius: 10px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba($color-black, .4);
transition: all .6s;

  &-shown {
    width: 73%;
    height: auto;
  }

  &-full-width {
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  }

  &-author {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1% 0 1% 0;
  }

  &-description {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    height: 100%;
  }

}
```

The jQuery - FYI I know this isn't very good but it's working for now and I'm going to come back to it later:

```
$(".gallery__image").click(function(){
        //Extract image information from clicked element
        let imgDescription=$(this).attr('image-description');
        let imgAuthor = $(this).attr('image-author');
        let imgUrl = $(this).attr('src');

        //Assign information to image popup
        $('.gallery__selected-image-full-width').attr('src', imgUrl);
        $('.gallery__selected-image-author').text(imgAuthor);
        $('.gallery__selected-image-description').text(imgDescription).css('width', '100%');

        //Fade out gallery and fade in image popup
        $(currentPage).fadeOut('slow');
        $('.gallery__pagination').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.gallery__selected-image-background').addClass('gallery__selected-image-background-shown');
        $('.gallery__selected-image').addClass('gallery__selected-image-shown');
```